# Is it true that $a^{k(p-1)+b} \;\stackrel{p}{\equiv} \;\;a^b\;$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

$$a^{k(p-1)+b} \;\stackrel{p}{\equiv} \;\;a^b\;?$$
$p$ prime number and $a,b,k\in\mathbb{N}^+$. And $p$ does not divide $a$.

According to Fermat's Little theorem $a^{p-1}\stackrel{p}{\equiv}1$. So $a^{k(p-1)} \stackrel{p}{\equiv}1$ by splitting into k parts and apply modulus independently we get $1^k = 1$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $(a,p)=1$  using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html) $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$

So, $a^{k(p-1)}\equiv1^k\equiv1\pmod p$

In fact, if $a^x\equiv a^y\pmod p$ where $(a,p)=1$ and integers $y, x(>y)$

$\implies a^{x-y}\equiv1\pmod p$

We can prove if $d=ord_pa, d$ divides $(x-y)$

As $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p,$  so $ord_pa$ divides $p-1$

If $(p-1)$ divides $(x-y), d$ will divide $(x-y)$

Comment: Is this true as well a^((p-1)+b) ≡ a^b (mod p)?

Comment: @Alex, $k$ can be any integer including $1$

Answer (score 0):

$$(a,p)=1\stackrel{\text{Fermat's l.t.}}\implies a^{k(p-1)}+b=\left(a^k\right)^{p-1}+b=1+b\pmod p$$

So the LHS above equals $\;a^b\;$ iff $\,a^b=1+b\pmod p\,$ , which in general will be false; take, for example, $\;b=-1\pmod p\,$

**Added after the question was changed:** Under the same arguments as above:

$$a^{k(p-1)+b}=\left(a^k\right)^{p-1}a^b=1\cdot a^b\pmod p=a^b\pmod p$$

since $\,(a,p)=1\iff (a^k,p)=1\;,\;\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb N$

Comment: sorry somebody edited my question incorrectly. Please check it now

Comment: @Alex, check the added stuff to my answer.