# Efficient modular exponentation of powers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Is there any way to efficiently compute $(((\mathrm{base}^{M_1})^{M_2})^{M_3} \dots )^{M_n}$ modulo $P$, where $P$ is prime? One way is to repeatedly do modular exponentiation for each of the powers. Another way, we could compute the [Multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) and powers thereafter would just be 1. Are there any alternative ways to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF $P$ divides $b,$ the remainder will be $0$

Else  $(b,P)=1$

$$((b^{M_1})^{M_2})^{M_3}\cdots)^{M_n}=b^{M_1\cdot M_2\cdot M_3\cdots M_n}$$

As $P$ is prime, $a^{P-1}\equiv\pmod P$ if $(a,P)=1$ using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html).

So, we need to find $M_1\cdot M_2\cdot M_3\cdots M_n\pmod {(P-1)}$

Then use repeated exponentiation.

Comment: It works, but could you please tell me how did you arrive at M1⋅M2⋅M3⋯Mn(mod(P−1)) .. I am unable to relate this to fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @jack_carver, please have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384199/akp-1b-modp-here-p-is-a-prime-number-and-a-b-k-is-an-integer-greater-tha